# Cannot write on TimeMachine data disk - told "Don't have enough permissions to write to '/Volumes' - files say (unknown) read&write

Tags: time-machine, permission, time-capsule

Cannot write on TimeMachine data disk - told "Don't have enough permissions to write to '/Volumes' - files say (unknown) read&write, staff read&write, everyone read&write

Details: I have a brand new laptop but am using an old AirPort TimeCapsule - I've been able to download files directly to it from my previous Mac, but not this new one. What should I do? I'm using uTorrent to download files.

I can't seem to add **username** to the Sharing & Permissions - and can't figure out how to change the Information / Access of the TimeCapsule drive either?

Answer (score 1):

So I assume you don't keep anything valuable in there (those files will NOT be backed up). I also suppose you connect to the TC share using SMB or AFP or the Finder windows sidebar: just check the credentials with which you are connecting (clic on TC in side bar, clic "Connect as..." in top bar). I never had any luck trying to change user permissions on a share from another machine. I believe you should check AirPort Utility/File Sharing/Secure Shared Disks/With accounts looking for user credentials, following these instructions: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202254. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

esaruoho... only TM should be allowed to write on a TM disk. You don't usually download anything from the disk: you should choose "Enter Time Machine" from its menu instead and restore the files you need from the Time Machine interface. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @SteveP - I've used the same timemachine drive for copying and retaining files for quite some time. The issue is being able to write to it or not. I can write to it with Finder no problem - but saving there with uTorrent gave me issues.